# Function App runs fine locally but fails when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, go, azure-functions

Following Microsoft Quick Start for Function App with Go (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-other?tabs=go%2Cwindows)

I was able to successfully run the code locally on my Windows computer. I continued to follow the steps to deploy the Function App to Azure portal and when try to run the Function App at the /api/HttpExample endpoint. It would fail to execute even though it runs fine locally.

Programming language used : Go 1.17.7

Links to source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-other?tabs=go%2Cwindows

Bindings used

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BB7788 - What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT - 
Webpage fails to load

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (working locally, wouldn't load when deployed), but I am running Linux locally. The error message I got was:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I was creating the Azure Function App through the VS Code Azure extension, and the default OS when creating a Function App is Windows:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code creating Function App]

The clue was to select the `Advanced` option and select OS->Linux. With the AZ CLI you need to add the option `--os-type Linux`, e.g.:

```bash
az functionapp create --os-type Linux --resource-group hellogorgplinux --consumption-plan-location eastus --runtime node --runtime-version 10 --functions-version 3 --name hellogoapplinux --storage-account hellogostglinux
```